# How to make responsive component?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

I have created three child component for main content (excluding header and header)

So the first component is not becoming responsive.

Here is the code:

```
<div className="row" style={{marginTop:'30px',}}>
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style={{display:'-webkit-inline-box', padding:'0px',}}>
            <label style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',margin: '5px 10px 5px 5px', position:'relative', float:'left',}} htmlFor="Airport_List">Airport :</label>
            <select value={this.state.airport} onChange={this.handleAirportChange} className="form-control" style={{width:'140px'}}>
            <option value="London">London</option>
            <option value="Houston">Houston</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
            <option value="Moscow">Moscow</option>
            </select> 

        </div> 

        <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style={{display:'-webkit-inline-box', padding:'0px',}}>

            <span className="fa fa-plane" style={{padding:'5px',fontSize:'20px',}}></span>
            <label style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',margin: '5px 10px 5px 5px',}} htmlFor="Flight No">Flight :</label>
            <input style={{
            width:'150px',
            margin: '0',
            outline: '0',
            border: '1px solid #e6ecf0',
            padding:'5px',
            borderRadius: '3px',backgroundColor:'#ffffff',color: 'rgb(158, 158, 158)',}} onChange={this.handleFlightChange}  type="text" id="flightNo" name="flight_no" className="form__input" placeholder="Flight NO"  required/>

        </div>

        <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

            <div style={{float:'right', display:'-webkit-inline-box',margin:'5px',}}>

            <label style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',margin: '5px 6px 5px 5px',}} htmlFor="Date">Date :</label>
            <div className='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8' style={{left:'12px',}}>
            <DateTimePicker 
              onChange={this.onDateChange}
              value={this.state.date}
              minDate={new Date()} 
              name="datetime"

            />
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{width:'100px', fontSize:'12px'}} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
               Fetch
          </Button>

         </div>

         <div className="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">

            <div style={{position:'relative', bottom: '10px',}}>
           <Fab color={this.state.color} onClick={()=>this.RecordAudio(this.state.color)}>
             {this.state.icon}
           </Fab>
           </div> 

         </div> 

        </div>
```

For Date I have used react-datetime-picker([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker))

So in full screen it's coming like this

[image: Full Screen Layout]

But If Shrink the browser screen it becomes like this :

[image: Not Responsive]

This has never happened before.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: yes. plz provide jdfiddle link. we are not able to replicate it. thanks

Comment: @NirajKaushal I have sent all the code of jsx still I have tried to copy the whole component in jsfiddle link here https://jsfiddle.net/mohammadkhan01/umx8d3fg/

Comment: @XenioGracias I have given link of jsfiddle above

Comment: @NirajKaushal have you tried?

Comment: @Kramer jsfiddle example is not working. Did you check Rishabh's answer?

Comment: @NirajKaushal jsfiddle will not work since. My code is dependent on certain things like package and state, so maybe because compiler error I just gave you the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate version of the bootstrap and also make sure you have this meta tag in your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code which looks like as follows

```
<div className="row" style={{marginTop:'30px',}}>
    <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style={{display:'-webkit-inline-box', padding:'0px',}}>
        <label style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',margin: '5px 10px 5px 5px', position:'relative', float:'left',}} htmlFor="Airport_List">Airport :</label>
        <select value={this.state.airport} onChange={this.handleAirportChange} className="form-control" style={{width:'140px'}}>
          <option value="London">London</option>
          <option value="Houston">Houston</option>
          <option value="California">California</option>
          <option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
          <option value="Moscow">Moscow</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style={{display:'-webkit-inline-box', padding:'0px',}}>
      <span className="fa fa-plane" style={{padding:'5px',fontSize:'20px',}}> </span>
      <label style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',margin: '5px 10px 5px 5px',}} htmlFor="Flight No">Flight :</label>
      <input style={{
        width:'150px',
        margin: '0',
        outline: '0',
        border: '1px solid #e6ecf0',
        padding:'5px',
        borderRadius: '3px',backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
        color: 'rgb(158, 158, 158)',}}  
        onChange={this.handleFlightChange}  
        type="text" 
        id="flightNo" 
        name="flight_no" 
        className="form__input" 
        placeholder="Flight NO"  required/>
    </div>

    <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

    <div style={{float:'right', display:'-webkit-inline-box',margin:'5px',}}>

        <label style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff',margin: '5px 6px 5px 5px',}} htmlFor="Date">Date :</label>
        <div className='input-group date' id='datetimepicker8' style={{left:'12px',}}>
          <DateTimePicker
            onChange={this.onDateChange}
            value={this.state.date}
            minDate={new Date()}
            name="datetime"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{width:'100px', fontSize:'12px'}} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Fetch</Button>
    </div>

    <div className="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <div style={{position:'relative', bottom: '10px',}}>
        <Fab
          color={this.state.color}
          onClick={() => this.RecordAudio(this.state.color)}
        >{this.state.icon}</Fab>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please add `meta tag` suggested by Rishab if you are not using it.

Comment: I have already added in index.html file `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` also used the meta tag provided by Rishab